# What is the meaning of these specific words: "не ахти", "напряг"?

Tags: перевод, значения, порядок-слов

I'm newbie in both English and Russian, so sorry.
But Russian is pretty much more difficult for me... Trying to translate few sentences for about a hour... :) I'm especially confused by two words and their usage in conjunction with other ones. Can't understand at all!
К тому же, *по деньгам у них - не **ахти***. Но вот за что я ручаюсь - я не был у них в голове, не телепат, но выглядят и ведут себя они намного веселее и раскованнее, чем у нас. *Нету у людей **напряга***.
Or maybe this sentences are wrongly composed and there are no meaning at all?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As user4419802 posted - you are reading the spoken language, which is hard. Not only because spoken/slang words are not present in dictionaries, but also because in several years they may vanish from the language, and so, time spent on learning these words is not spent effectively, especially when you are starting to learn new language.

Comment: "по деньгами" is totally wrong, it can be either "по деньгам" or "с деньгами".

Comment: I see nothing wrong with studying the spoken language at any given time in history. The fact is that "snapshots" of the vernacular of any era are immortalized in movies, songs, books and web content that can be accessed at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Не ахти* means *not too well*. *Напряг* is a slanguish word meaning *trouble*. I hope that would be sufficient to catch the rest.

The problem is you're trying to understand a "spoken" language which is not a good place to start.

Comment: **Напряг** = **strain** or **stress**.  It can be due to trouble, it can be due to lack of resources (money, living space, etc.), it can be just in one's head.  "*Нету у людей напряга*" means they don't appear to be ***stressed out***, or ***under strain***.

Comment: Also, not "***по** деньгами у них*", but "***с** деньгами у них*".

Wish you success in your studies!  Both English and Russian are great languages deserving full effort on the part of the student.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Slang words are used often in different ways. I deliberately chose "trouble" as it means both "real problem" and "concern". Just like "напряг" does. And saying "по деньгам" is a common spoken practice nowadays. I'm agree it's not a good habit but too many people say so.

Comment: "По деньгам" ≠ "По деньгамИ".  The preposition "по" requires **dative** case, not **instrumental**.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Ah, I didn't see this. Thus it may be either "по деньгам" or "с деньгами". Not sure if it's worth choosing either option to correct it.

Comment: напряг=напряжение, стресс

Comment: @Paul The dictionaries of contemporary slang state that "напряг" is a synonym to slanguish anglicism "трабл".

Comment: @user4419802 I'd just given etymology.

Comment: @Paul Yes, sure. Normally "напряг" is singular past tense of the verb "напрячь" (to strain).